# Printing except messages in flask templates via jinja2

Tags: python, html, flask, jinja2, psycopg2

I've create a function to connect to a db that prints a 'failure to connect to db' message if no connection is made:

```
  def connectToDB():
        connectionString = 'dbname=reportingdb1 user=red_gui password=RadnfgoInd host=10.100.51.42'
  try:
     return psycopg2.connect(connectionString)
  except:
     print ("Failure to connect to db")
```

In my views.py files in the index section, this function is called straight away and in my testing environment prints the except failure statement into my terminal when I deliberately use the wrong credentials for the db (for testing purposes).

```
 ####Index Page
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@app.route('/index', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
          connectToDB()
          form = StaffNames()
          if form.validate_on_submit():
                  return redirect('/results')
          return render_template('index.html',title='Search Page',form=form)
```

My problem is, I want this message to print out on the web page. I've tried using `return` instead of `print` and that hasn't worked. I've also tried attempting to store the except message in a variable, then in my templates/index.html file, call it through jinja2 curly brackets.For examples I tried:
in views.py

```
except:
     noconnect = "Failure to connect to db"
```

then in my index.html:

```
{{ noconnect }}
```

But this too hasn't worked. What would be the best practice to do this?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplify `connectToDB` so it only connects to the DB and nothing else.

```
def connectToDB():
    connectionString = 'dbname=reportingdb1 user=red_gui password=RadnfgoInd host=10.100.51.42'
    psycopg2.connect(connectionString)
```

Handle any potential exception in the view (but be aware that catching *all* exceptions is not a good practice).

```
 ####Index Page
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@app.route('/index', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    exception = None
    try:
        connectToDB()
    except:
        exception = 'Failure to connect to db'

    form = StaffNames()
    if not exception:
        if form.validate_on_submit():
            return redirect('/results')

    return render_template('index.html',title='Search Page', form=form, exception=exception)
```

Place `{{ exception }}` somewhere in your `index.html`

Comment: Thanks, but i'm getting error `local variable 'form' referenced before assignment`

Comment: Just to add, this only happens when I deliberately input the wrong password for the db- the whole virtualenv app fails at this point. This means I can't actually look at the index page to see if the connect to db error that I have tried to generate appears. The app fails rather than simply telling me I can't connect to the db. How can I stop the app from falling over on each unsuccessful connection to the db?

Comment: Actually i've worked it out, the `form = StaffNames()` needed to be outside of the `if` statement, so I placed it straight after `def index():` and it's worked. I'll accept your answer (as it was perfect otherwise!) if you change this bit.

Answer (score 0):

Web frameworks generally require objects to be passed via context to the views and templates. You have to pass in the objects in the `render_template`:

```
. . .

error = connectToDB()

return render_template('index.html', title='Search Page',
                       form=form, error=error)
```

Then in your template, use: `{{ error }}`

Another way to do this that is more Django-like is to create a dictionary for your data:

```
error = 'error message'
test = 'test'

. . .

data = {
    'error': error,
    'test': test
}
```

Then return your `render_template` like so:

```
return render_template('index.html', title='Search Page',
                       form=form, **data)
```

The double stars make it so you can still do this: `{{ error }}`. Otherwise, you will have to do this: `{{ data.error }}`

Comment: Thanks i'll give this a try, but could you explain something to me so I understand. Why doesn't `error = connectToDB()`  simply make `error` a variable that contains the connectToDB() function?

Comment: I've tried this, but it's just printing "None" on my webpage where I've placed the {{ error }} . It's not indicating that the db cannot be reached despite me inputting the wrong credentials.

Comment: `error = connectToDB()` gives a name to any return values from calling that function. If the DB connection succeeds, you will get whatever this gives you, `psycopg2.connect(connectionString)`. If it fails, you will get the error message, as you want. Given this information, you might consider refactoring your `connectToDB` function, as you may not need to return that `psycopg2` object to your view.